# File open in tabs automatically

Tags: vim, gvim

I want to set up vim so that it opens automatically in tab and not in buffers.  I know that I could use `alias gvim='gvim -p'` or some such shell mapping but I am wondering if there is a way to do that from vim itself.

So, what I want is for

```
gvim ook eek monkey
```

to be equivalent in behaviour to

```
gvim -p ook eek monkey
```

aka a tab is opened for each file/buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:tabnew` and `:tabedit` in [`:help tabpage`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#tab-page-intro). (I'm not sure if you can (or want to) re-map `:edit`)

[(**Edit** There is a related and helpful SO discussion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers)

(**Edit** to match your refined question)
I doubt it will be less hassle than `alias gvim=gvim -p`, but [using `autocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#VimEnter) (and some Vimscript, everything in your `.vimrc`) this might be possible.  (But I'm not knowledgeable enough to go into detail with this.)

Comment: Sorry, could not see how to set gvim behaviour to open multiple tabs if there is more than one filename on the command line.  Edited question to make it more clear.